# Send empty string for a SharePoint lookup Id will raise this error "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'."

Tags: power-automate

I have the following "Send http request to SharePoint", to update a lookup field Id for a list item:-
[image]

the above will work fine, but if i want to clear the lookup ID, by send empty string, i will get this error:-

Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'. See the inner exception for more details.
clientRequestId: ed6b85fb-4be0-4d19-bf6f-fc01a7bd84fd
serviceRequestId: 584d21a0-101f-c000-e1f8-7cba6e8c3d6f

[image]

so how i can fix this issue?

**EDIT**

I added a condition to check if the var is empty >> and if so to set it as null:-
[image]

but i will get the same error:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to `null` rather than an empty string.

In the screen capture below, the expression used to set the CategoryId in the **Compose REST request body action** is `if(equals(variables('CategoryId'),''),null,variables('CategoryId'))`

[image: Screen capture of flow]

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but the value will not be always be null,, this depend if the user inside the form enter the Id or not.. now if the user enter the id everything will work fine, but if the user clear the value,, then the flow will fail.. thanks

Comment: You can use an If condition or expression to check for an empty string and, if you get one,  you can convert it to null.

Comment: just tried this .. but i got the same error!! can you check my edit please?

Comment: @johnGu I just updated my answer to address your edited question

Comment: the exporession need to be as follow `if(equals(variables('currentItemStoreID'),Blank()),null,concat('"',variables('currentItemStoreID'),'"'))` but i got an error to enter a valid json..

Comment: Blank is not a valid function. The list of valid string functions can be found here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#string-functions. Also, you don't need to enclose the the lookup Id in quotes since SharePoint is expecting a number (or null).